# Exclude all except specified attributes in query - Eloquent Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, arrays, eloquent, model, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.2, the following Eloquent query will remove the attributes that are specified in the array. I want to do a similar operation in which I exclude all attributes by default and only include the ones that are in an array. How can I do this? I suspect that the answer may have something to do with defining a custom $appends array on the model before running the query, but I don't know how to do this.

```
return MyModel::all()->each(function($row) {
    $row->setHidden([
        'attribute_1',
        'attribute_2'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model

```
protected $excludedColumns = ['attr1', 'attr2'];

  public function scopeExcludeColumns($query) {
        return $query->select(array_diff(Schema::getColumnListing($this->table), $this->excludedColumns));
    }
```

Use:

```
$result = Model::excludedColumns()->all();
```

another option is to setup $hidden property on model by folowing

```
protected $hidden = array('attr1','attr2');
```

but it will exclude this fields from model only when call `$result->toArray;` or `$result->toJson();`